# Easiest way to label rows in a datagrid

Tags: c#, xml, datagrid, dataset, datagridrowheader

I have a dataset that reads in an xml WebResponse and i then extract and merge tables from this dataset how can I add 7 hard coded labels to the merged table to display in datagrid, the labels with always be the same values and the order will always be the same.

I guess to make it easy I want to add 7 row headers to the table? To be displayed with a datagrid.

What I Tried

```
 WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(m_uri);
        WebResponse rsp;
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "text/xml";
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
        writer.WriteLine(buildXml().ToString());
        writer.Close();
        rsp = req.GetResponse();

        //Get the Posted Data
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream());
        string rawXml = reader.ReadToEnd();
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(rawXml);

        //Use XPath to Navigate the Document
        int status = Convert.ToInt32(xml.SelectSingleNode(@"/RatingServiceSelectionResponse/Response/ResponseStatusCode").InnerText);
        if (status == 1)
        {




            StringReader srxml = new StringReader(rawXml);

            DataSet dsAuthors = new DataSet("RatedShipment");
            dsAuthors.ReadXml(srxml);

            dsAuthors.EnforceConstraints = false;

            DataTable Shipment = dsAuthors.Tables[2];
            DataTable TotalCharges = dsAuthors.Tables[8];
            DataTable table = new DataTable("UPS Service");

            Shipment.Merge(TotalCharges);
            Shipment.Columns.Remove("RatedShipmentWarning");
            Shipment.Columns.Remove("CurrencyCode");
            Shipment.Rows.RemoveAt(7);
            DataColumn UPSService = new DataColumn();
            UPSService.DataType = typeof(string); 
            UPSService.ColumnName = "UPS Service";
            Shipment.Columns.Add(UPSService);
            Shipment.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "UPS Ground";
            Shipment.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value = "UPS Three Day";
            Shipment.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value = "UPS Second Day A.M.";
            Shipment.Rows[3].Cells[0].Value = "UPS Second Day";
            Shipment.Rows[6].Cells[0].Value = "UPS Next Day Air Saver";
            Shipment.Rows[4].Cells[0].Value = "UPS Next Day Air Early A.M.";
            Shipment.Rows[5].Cells[0].Value = "UPS Next Day Air";



        dataGridView1.DataSource = Shipment;


        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable To Process: Please Check All Fields Are Entered");
        }
```

But the Cells After the rows is not correct.

Comment: your application is asp.net or windows-forms app?

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to do this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagrid.Rows) {
    row.Cells(0).Value = "yourtext";
}
```

Comment: for row headers? from top to bottom?

Comment: you mean u need to rename the headers of the grid? which headers you are talking about?

Comment: I need the first cell in each row to be a specific so row 1 row 2 row 3 row 4 from top to bottom explaining what each row is.

Comment: Ok, I changed (0) to [0] and added a column in the datagridview properties. And now i get all the information I need but when I sort any of the columns all the values I added erase from the grid instead of sorting with the rest of the rows?

Comment: sorry for the [] i am using notepad :), as for the sorting i guess it will be an issue for you since your data in the first rows are static, I think you should add the static values in the database records then for each row.

Comment: I have posted a code snip of my app i am only  weeks into programming i have a it back ground but this is all new to me i have only learned what i could reading through this site and msdn.